# how to pass the data from the parent component to the modal in ngZorros

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ng-zorro-antd

Iam new to the ant ng-Zorros, where i need to send the data from the component to the modal , i tried to use the documentation of ngzorros ,but not able to send data .I have a table component where iam having column called color, if we click the showmore in color column modal have to open ,in that modal i need to show the color data in the modal, modal is opening but didn't find anything to send data from the table component to the modal component .any suggestions would be helpful

```
item-table.html
----------------
   <td  ><a  nz-tooltip="Click To Open" class="text-color" (click)="showModal(data.color)">Show More </a></td>

item-table.ts
----------------
   showModal(data:any) {
      console.log(data);
      
      const modal = this.modal.create({
        nzTitle: '',
        nzContent: ItemModalComponent,
        nzViewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef,
        nzClosable: false,
       
      })
    }

item.modal.ts
-------------------
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-modal',
  templateUrl: './item-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-modal.component.less']
})
export class ItemModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You've to pass your data to '@Input InputData' in your modal component via the "nzComponentParams" of the modal service, your code should be like below

```
 showModal(data:any) {
  console.log(data);
  const modal = this.modal.create({
    nzTitle: '',
    nzContent: ItemModalComponent,
    nzViewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef,
    nzClosable: false,
    nzComponentParams: {
      InputData: data
    }
   
  })
}
```

Then get it on your component

```
export class ItemModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input InputData: any;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(InputData);
  }
}
```